# Configuration Settings those cannot be overridden in lower level web.config files

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, configuration, web-config

This is a general question and is not about any particular issue that I am facing right now.

As configuration settings in the child level can override the ones in parent level,errors can occur when you have 2 web.config files one redefining configuration settings that you cannot override such as authentication or session state.
Issue happens when you have authentication / session state set on the lower level web.config and also in higher level web.config.

Is there any other configuration settings like these ?

Comment: Why you override in second web.config if you don't want to do it?

Comment: Issue happens when we are trying to integrate a 3rd party application like blog engine.net.These applications come with a web.config file . There are chances that 2 applications can have configuration settings in two different configuration files which cannot be overridden.If there is, then there would be errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [lock configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178693.aspx) in parent config. Each configuration element offers [several attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228167.aspx) for locking overrides. You should identify wich config settings are necessary for your application (or deployment) in parent config and lock them so that 3rd party application do not override them.